# How can I get a part of the value of class attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<tr>
    <td class="option_name_twitter">Something</td>
    <td class="option_loading">
        <img src="img/checked_successfully.png">
    </td>                        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="option_name_instagram">Something else</td>
    <td class="option_loading">
        <img src="img/checked_successfully.png">
    </td>                        
</tr>
```

And here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', "img[src$='checked_successfully.png']", function () {
    var name = $(this).closest('td.option_loading').sibilings('td.^option_name_').attr('class');
})
```

I'm trying to get the last part of the classname's value of an element that starts with `option_name_`. So the expected result is either `twitter` or `instagram`. How can I do that?

Comment: Here is a tiny snippet to extract the class name. Should be the cheapest version (no regex, splitting, popping, whatever):  

`name = name.substr( 1 + name.lastIndexOf('_') );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting the `class` from the sibling `td`, splitting it in to an array using `_`, then `pop()` off the last element to get the value you need. Something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', "img[src$='checked_successfully.png']", function() {
  var name = $(this).closest('td.option_loading').prev('td').attr('class');
  var site = name.split('_').pop();
  console.log(site);
})
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="option_name_twitter">Something</td>
    <td class="option_loading">
      <img src="img/checked_successfully.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="option_name_instagram">Something else</td>
    <td class="option_loading">
      <img src="img/checked_successfully.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You should however note that using the `class` string in this way is not ideal, as it's very easily broken. Adding another class at the end of the attribute will break this code. A much better approach would be to store the value you need in its own data attribute - assuming you have access to edit the HTML.